# How to Force Project/Solution to open in Visual Studio with Administrator privileges?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

**First of all I know how to set properties on devenv.exe so that VS opens by default with administrator privileges. My question is how to set priviledges on VS Solution/Project.**

I have a VS project (not made by me), which on opening gives following message.

[image]

So I have to open VS with Administrator Privileges and then this project opens fine. But how do you set such condition in VS solution/Project?

Comment: Fix the permissions on the project directory?

Comment: @MickyD: No, you can do this at project level.

Comment: You can't have some parts of a process running _elevated_ and others not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Privilege Level to Run this program as an administrator in windows for the devenv.exe. For this you have to take properties of devenv.exe by right clicking it and selecting properties. From properties window go to compatibility tab and then select the *Run this program as an administrator* checkbox. Please see the attached screen shot

[image]

Comment: But this condition is related to Project/Solution. I have other projects which do not have such condition. So I deducted that this is related to Project/Solution settings.

Comment: If you do not run VS as administrator you will have privilege issues like file creation etc, for these condition you wont event get this warning but you would face privilege issue. So its generally good idea to apply it on VS devenv.exe and I see no harm in it.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, Adil is correct.  For example I run into this if I open a solution with an IIS project, however it does not complain about the class library project or console app in the same solution.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal read the error message. The problem is with the project directory permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Visual Studio select properties, choose compatiblility tab and in Privilege Level select checkbox "Run this program as an administrator"

Next time if you open any project that will be open in administrator privilege.